# Make click on row behave like click on checkbox in "move comments to chat" option in mod menu on question

Tags: feature-request, design, moderator-tools

Right now, clicking on the row behaves like clicking on the radio button.

> [image]

Notice how the radio button flashes indicating that it's being clicked. The checkbox should be checked instead.

Comment: I almost missed the fact that it's clicking on the radio button. Maybe to demonstrate this more effectively, you could click the other option below, then click the line to show that it's clicking the radio button rather than the checkbox?

Comment: @SonictheBracketedHedgehog, if I click on another item, current item will be collapsed, so this image will be not that representative =/